# How to know when a tcp message was sent

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server, validation

In an online farm-like game I need to validate on server client's long processes like building a house. Say the house need 10 minutes to be built. Client sends "Start build" message asynchronously over TCP connection when it starts building house and "Finish build" when it thinks the house is built. On server I need to validate that house was built in at least 10 minutes. The issue is server doesn't know when client sent "start build" and "finish build" messages. It knows when message was received, but there is a network lag, possible network failures and messages can be long enough to take a few tcp segments. As I understand the time client took to send message can be up to few minutes and depends on client TCP configuration. The question is: is there a way to know when message was issued on client side? If not, how can I guarantee time period in that message was sent, possibly some server TCP configuration? Some timeout in that server either receives the message or fails would be ok. Any other solutions to main task I may not think about are also welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why even care about that? You know when the house started to be built, have the server send the client the message after 10 minutes.

Comment: House build can be interrupted and/or other worker with different work speed can start build it later. For user it should look as smooth as possible, no build time changes from server, so server does only optimistic validation better letting client to cheat than punishing honest client. Another reason I don't want server to run separate tasks to figure out when to send "Finish build" to clients that are possibly are not connected anymore. If there is no other option, I may be will have to do something like that, but I want to search for a way to limit client lag ambiguity first.

Comment: If you just want to reduce the lag and don't bother clients cheating. Than I would recommend using UDP as it is truly asynchronous and faster than TCP in most cases. As you don't want to transfer files but very short messages it might be optimal for your game (like for the most other multiplayer games).

Comment: UDP has same issues and even worse - with it I don't even know if message was sent or not, not only when it was sent.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your main issue is not related to TCP itself (because the described scenario could also happen using UDP) but to the chronology of your messages and securing that the timeline has not been faked.

So the only case you want to avoid is the following:

```
STARTED send at 09:00:00 and received at 09:00:30 (higher latency)
FINISHED send at 09:10:00 and received at 09:10:01 (lower latency)
```

As it looks to the server as if there were only 9.5 minutes spent constructing your virtual building. But the client didn't cheat it was only that the first message had a higher latency than the second.

The other way around would be no problem:

```
STARTED send at 09:00:00 and received at 09:00:01 (lower latency)
FINISHED send at 09:10:00 and received at 09:10:30 (higher latency)
```

or

```
STARTED send at 09:00:00 and received at 09:00:10 (equal latency)
FINISHED send at 09:10:00 and received at 09:10:10 (equal latency)
```

As at least 10 minutes elapsed between the receiving of the two messages.

Unfortunately there is no way to ensure the client does not cheat by using timestamps or such. It does not matter if your client writes the timestamps in the messages or if the protocol does it for you. There are two reasons for that:

- Even if your client does not cheat, the system clocks of client and
  server might not be in sync
- All data written in the network packet are just bytes and can be manipulated. Someone could use a RAW socket and fake the entire TCP layer

So the only thing that is for sure is the time when the messages were received by the server. A simple solution would be to send some sort of RETRY message containing the time left to the client if the server thinks that not enough time elapsed when receiving the FINISHED message. So the client could adjust the construction animation and then send the FINISHED message again, depending on how much time was left.

Comment: The issue is exactly as you described - thanks for nice illustrations I didn't provide. Server sees only time when it receives messages and it can be lesser or bigger than time between messages client sent. And yes, server can only validate this receive time, any timestamps could be faked.

Comment: I have think about RETRY solution, it would require some client logic and roll-backs user can see which we are trying to avoid. I would better forgive slightly cheating client than forcing normal client to redraw game or rollback progress.

Comment: The question is what is the time I have to forgive. In your example it is only 30 seconds, but see http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_time.htm#21_2 this book says 9 minutes! So question is how can I manage this time and reduce it to say 1 minute? As I understand socket timeout won't work because client can send little message chunks every 1 minute an whole message will still take a few minutes to deliver.

Comment: You could animate the rollback so nobody notices. But even better than RETRY messages would be using the UDP protocol, that should reduce your lags and if the lags are in the magnitude of minutes that the game won't make fun any more, so that is a problem you can't solve with software and is caused by the network in between.